# How to get the root directory path in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Is there a plugin for this problem or can it be solved using `dart:io`, because `path_provider` does not have a method for accessing the root directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this utility function:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Directory findRoot(FileSystemEntity entity) {
    final Directory parent = entity.parent;
    if (parent.path == entity.path) return parent;
    return findRoot(parent);
}
```

If you have a package such as [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), you can use it like this in your code:

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final Directory root = findRoot(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
```

Comment: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = './' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Comment: tried permission handler to get storage permission still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

use this package https://pub.dev/packages/external_path to get root Directory of the device.

```
      Future<void> getPath_1() async {
      var path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories();
      print(path);  // [/storage/emulated/0, /storage/B3AE-4D28]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

when we take path by:

1. getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() method gives =

> /data/user/0/com.crackhead.stacker/app_flutter/ and

2. getExternalStorageDirectory() method gives =

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.crackhead.stacker/files

soo here from 2nd one we see that internal storage path would be

> /storage/emulated/0/

and for SD-card I had to hard-code seeing from Z-archiver app where path was:

> /storage/4DC2-723F

and there corresponding directories would be:

> Internal Storage : Directory('/storage/emulated/0/');

> SD-card : Directory('/storage/4DC2-723F');

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Package [external_path](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path/example)  returns the path for top level storage.

First install the plugin:

```
flutter pub add external_path
```

Then import it:

```
import 'package:external_path/external_path.dart';
```

Finally run something like this:

```
var path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories();  // [/storage/emulated/0, /storage/B3AE-4D28] 2nd path refers to SD
```

Check out more here in the docs: https://pub.dev/documentation/external_path/latest/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35541800)

Answer (score -3):

The [Directory class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html) may have what you are looking for.

`var myDir = new Directory('path_to_root');`

Comment: each device will have different path bro, this is not an optimal solution