# How to list all local mp3 files on flutter2(null safety)?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The code should be working on flutter2, with android and ios(if possible)

Answer (score 1):

### Searching for files

- Do you want to simplify your life? Use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/glob):

```dart
import 'package:glob/glob.dart';

Stream<File> search(Directory dir) {
    return Glob("**.mp3")
      .list(root: dir.path)
      .where((entity) => entity is File)
      .cast<File>();
}
```

- Do you want to avoid adding a new dependency in your project? Manipulate the `Directory` itself:

```
Stream<File> search(Directory dir) {
  return dir
    .list(recursive: true)
    .where((entity) => entity is File && entity.path.endsWith(".mp3"))
    .cast<File>();
}
```

### Defining the search scope

You'll also need a `Directory` where you'll search for MP3 files.

- Is it the root directory (i.e. search **ALL** the files in the device)? Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596799/9997212).
- Is it another directory? Pick one from [this package](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/path_provider-library.html).

### Usage

```dart
final Directory dir = /* the directory you obtained in the last section */;
await search(dir).forEach((file) => print(file));
```

Comment: The method 'list' isn't defined for the type 'Glob'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'list'.

Comment: Try adding `import 'package:glob/list_local_fs.dart';` at the top of your file.

Comment: No permissions found in manifest for: []22
when i ask for permissions

Comment: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = './' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)